# How to efficiently respond with large json data from server to client?

Tags: java, reactjs, http, optimization

I'm a beginner full-stack developer, I need help on how I can implement this feature efficiently.

I have a Mongodb collection that has 50K records, I will make a post request to delete some of the records and I need the deleted records back to the client to download them. The deleted records can be 300MB. This will only be done once, it's not a frequent request. Is it okay if I respond with the json data all at once? How can I implement this efficiently? I'm using spring-boot and react.

Comment: 300MB is really high for a few thousand rows. Does each row have very long strings, or binary data for icons or something?